# Webservice callout in Apex component used in EmailTemplate thrws Programmer Error: transaction committed or rolled back while performing api operation

Tags: apex, email-template, visualforce-component, callout, singleemailmessage

I have an email template which I need to build using many information , so I have used apex component

```
<c:EmailTemplateComp ObjectID="{!relatedTo.Id}" show_url="false"></c:ATEmailTemplate_FirstName>
```

and in the controller Im making a web service call out.

When I send the Email using Messaging.sendEmail it throws the error

> Programmer Error: transaction committed or rolled back while performing api operation: SendEmail

but if the remove the  web service call out the email is sent successfully.
Question : Is it not allowed to do a web service call out in apex component controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform a callout after DML, which Messaging.sendEmail performs. As a workaround, use [Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm) to first render the text (which can include the callout), and then perform sendEmail using the resulting output. You *can* perform a callout while sending an email, but the callout must be done first to avoid this error.